# Python code to loop though list of files and read specific line fails after first loop

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a python code to read through a specific line from list of files in a directory and below is my python code. For a practice I kept two csv files in the directory.
I'm reading the second line from each file and if the line is empty I want to print as 'Pass' otherwise as 'Fail'. The code reads the first file which has values in the second row and it prints correctly as 'fail' and that is all the output i'm getting from this code as its not printing anything for the second file. could somebody please help me out here.

```
        import os
        from itertools import islice            
        for filename in os.listdir(r"input_file_path"):
            f= open(os.path.join(r"input_file_path", filename))
            for line in islice(f,1,2):
                if line == None:
                    print(filename,'pass')
                else:
                    print(filename,'fail')
```

Comment: Empty line, if present in the file, never is `None`, it is `\n` (Linux/Mac) or `\r\n` (Windows).

Comment: You should use `if l.strip() == ''`

Comment: I replaced but it still skips the second file :(

Comment: I replaced `r"input_file_path"` with real directory name and code works correctly for multiple files in the directory.

Comment: Could you kindly check with a file which has only header. I was expecting this to be captured in the summary table with status as 'PASS' and the above code is not working as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have check it - your code works correctly.

It looks like you are contradicting yourself:

> ...and if the line is empty I want to print as 'fail' otherwise as
> 'pass'

> The code reads the first file which has values in the second row and
> it prints correctly as 'fail'

Check contents of the files you are reading in.
You could also put some `print` statements inside your code to be sure what exactly is happening during the program execution (e.g. which files are being read, what is the content of each line, etc).

Comment: I edited my question as i Want to print as 'pass' if there are no values in the second row from the file.
 I added a print statement but its only returning the 2nd row of the first file and returning nothing for the second file.
I added a row in the second file and it worked fine so my code does not work if there are no values in the second row